# Missing scrollbar from a Windows Form control if it is embedded in a WPF app

Tags: wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I have a windows form control which consists of a group box, a tab control, and a tab page with scroll bar, this is how it looks like in designer:

[image: Windows Form Control in designer]

After I embed this control inside a WPF control, when I compile and run the program, I found that the scrollbar is simply missing, as shown:

[image: WPF with windows form control]

Not only that, I can't scroll to the bottom of the windows form control by scrolling the middle mouse.

How to get the scrollbar to appear in WPF application?

This is my code:

The Windows Form user control code (`TabControlScrollBar`):

```
partial class TabControlScrollBar: UserControl
{
    public TabControlScrollBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 57);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(580, 446);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(572, 420);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 414);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(223, 78);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button2.Text = "button2";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 3);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(573, 48);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";
        // 
        // TabControlScrollBar
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
        this.Name = "TabControlScrollBar";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(583, 503);
        this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Scrollbarproblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Scrollbarproblem"
        xmlns:winformhost ="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:TabScrollWrapper x:Name="scrollbarme" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class TabScrollWrapper : WindowsFormsHost
{
    public TabScrollWrapper()
    {
        Child = new TabControlScrollBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload images to somewhere else. imgur is banned in my country :(

Comment: @tetralobita, can you use a VPN? StackOverflow.com is using imgur as the default place for image uploads.